# Enabling Thread Contention Montioring increases performance overhead

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks

In Java Docs , I found that if we enable the thread contention monitoring  then overhead will be there in targeted application .

This is overhead affects in response time or how it will affect the performance ?

Answer (score 0):

It just behaves as if your CPU is lamer, or as if your CPU takes some milliseconds off every one second. Because some CPU cycles are sunk in the contention monitering process.

Comment: I want to take cpu wait and block time of a particular request , if I enable this thing I will get any performance overhead in the targeted application ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. You are saying cpu cycles wasted when we enable thread contention monitoring .

Comment: @Deepak To be particular it's the accumulated time a particular thread has been blocked since the enabling of thread contention monitoring.

Comment: ya I know its functionality I am tracking cpu block and wait time for each request , but by default it is disabled We have to enable it by a flag or through java program if we enable that they told performance overhead will be there how can I measure this overhead ?

Comment: This would be rather hard, and maybe the only thing you can do is run your program both with and without thread contention monitoring, and measure the corresponding performance to the degree you are concerned with (throughput,  response time, etc..). This would be the simplest solution. Otherwise you have to consult those who built your VM, and most probably even them can't give you a precise anwser. There are just way too many factors inside this overhead. For example, a good CPU may suffer lower overhead. Different coding style has different overhead, etc..